# Receiving error when I am importing sklearn.ensemble

Tags: python

I am receiving the following error.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-89db614d07d0> in <module>()
----> 1 from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/tree/_classes.py in <module>()
     39 from ..utils.validation import check_is_fitted
     40 
---> 41 from ._criterion import Criterion
     42 from ._splitter import Splitter
     43 from ._tree import DepthFirstTreeBuilder

sklearn/tree/_criterion.pyx in init sklearn.tree._criterion()

cython_special.pyx in init scipy.special.cython_special()

ImportError: scipy.special._ufuncs_cxx does not export expected C variable _export_expit

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score -1):

I spend a number of time to achieve the problem. Let me tell you that `pip install scipy == 1.4.1`。